# Asynchronously monitor and interrupt a shell script

Tags: bash, shell, asynchronous, scripting, interrupt

I have a shell script that calls some data processing functions. These functions can be long-running.
I want to update the script to interrupt the running process in case a certain "status" is seen from an external source. Otherwise the program should complete normally.

I have written a monitor_status function and called is asynchronously. The function sends a kill command to the main process in case the status is found. I have the following questions on this

1. in case the kill -15 $ is invoked from monitor_status function, the cleanup function gets called twice. how can I prevent that?
2. If the main process completes normally, how should I terminate the monitor_status function?

Also please suggest if there is a better way to handle such a scenario and any other improvements I can make to the script

The bash script looks something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

function cleanup() {
  echo "cleanup invoked"
  if [[ -n "${child}" ]]; then
    echo "Stopping the child"
    kill "${child}" >/dev/null 2>&1 || true
  fi
  echo "cleanup done"
}

function main() { 
    echo "Starting main process"
    # do long running data processing
    echo "Exiting Main"
}

function monitor_status() { 
    echo "checking status"
    $Status = get_status
    if [[ $Status = "Terminate" ]]; then
        echo "Alert Alert!!!"
        kill -15 $$
    fi
    sleep 5
    done
}

monitor_status &
main &
trap cleanup SIGTERM EXIT
child=$!
wait "${child}"
```

Comment: `trap cleanup SIGTERM EXIT` -> `trap cleanup EXIT`

Comment: @kamilcuk So the SIGTERM is causing the cleanup to run twice?

Comment: The SIGTERM is causing it to run once...then the EXIT is causing it to run once. Don't do both. SIGTERM can have its own trap that causes the process to exit, which will trigger EXIT.

Comment: Also, I suspect `$Status = get_status` is an error. Paste this into shellcheck.net. Did you mean `Status=$(get_status)`?

Comment: $Status = get_status is just a mock of an external API call to fetch the status.